# Poincaré inequality holds on Riemannian manifolds (min max principle)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

In YuChang Xia's book *"Eigenvalues on Riemannian Manifolds"* Page 4 equation (1.16）Poincaré inequality:

[image]

I want to know which manifold(s)/function(s) can make the inequality hold. What if we request $f$ is a eigenfunction? Since I need the inequality holds in my research work. Is there any reference or paper?

Comment: if $\{f_i\}$ group a complete orthonormal basis of $M$ because then we can integeral by part and expension it, then this is true, so it is at least true for compact manifold(allow boundary).

Comment: The inequality is trivial: define $\lambda_1$ to be the infimum ratio of mean square gradient over mean square. Then obviously $\lambda_1$ is at most the ratio of mean square gradient to mean square for any function.

Comment: @BenMcKay Admittedly that's a liberal interpretation of the question, but I took to mean 'Which manifolds admit a Poincare inequality (with $\lambda_1 > 0$)?' I admit I don't know much about this, but I think the question is not so simple in the non-compact case, for complete manifolds say. A quick search suggests that this is related to the volume growth of $M$, as well as its Ricci curvature, see for example Besson-Courtois-Hersonsky 'Poincare inequality on complete Riemannian manifolds with Ricci curvature bounded below'.